# Hide a div if php echo content is empty

Tags: javascript, php

```
<div class="botontour"><a href="<?php echo $currentItem['video'];?
>">Video Tour 3D</a></div>
```

I want to hide the entire "botontour" div if the php echo has no return.

Comment: this snippet will get you going `<?php if (!empty($currentItem['video'])) { ?> 
 <div class="botontour"><a href="<?php echo $currentItem['video'];?>">Video Tour 3D</a></div>
<?php } ?>`. The if block will execute only if `$currentItem['video']` is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you can check if it's [empty](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php) :

```
<?php
if (!empty($currentItem['video'])) {
?>
    <div class="botontour"><a href="<?= $currentItem['video'];?>">Video Tour 3D</a></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Of course it was that easy. Two days stuck on this and didn't see the obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if(isset($currentItem['video']) && !empty($currentItem['video'])){
    ?>

 <div class="botontour"><a href="<?= $currentItem['video'];?>">Video Tour 3D</a></div>

<?php  } >
```

Comment: you can not have echo inside echo

Comment: didn't notice the echo inside the a tag

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

> empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

```
<?php

if(!empty($currentItem['video'])) { ?>

<div class="botontour"><a href="<?php echo $currentItem['video'];
>">Video Tour 3D</a></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strlen() : https://php.net/strlen

```
    <?php if(strlen($currentItem['video']) != 0) { ?>
    <div class="botontour"><a href="<?php echo $currentItem['video'];?
     >">Video Tour 3D</a></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Or Empty() : https://php.net/empty

```
    <?php if(!empty($currentItem['video'])) { ?>
    <div class="botontour"><a href="<?php echo $currentItem['video'];?
     >">Video Tour 3D</a></div>
    <?php } ?>
```